# Sort by value in list within list

Tags: r, vector

Here is the list I have

```r
example <- list(list(vals = list(1, 2, 3), param = list(4,5,6), p.val = 0.5),
 list(vals = list(1, 2, 3), param = list(4,5,6), p.val = 0.2), 
 list(vals = list(1, 2, 3), param = list(4,5,6), p.val = 1.2), 
 list(vals = list(1, 2, 3), param = list(4,5,6), p.val = 0.9))
```

How can I sort this list in ascending order by their p-val?

My main issue is that the only solution I seem to see as possible is a for loop running through this entire list, which in reality is 100k elements.

EDIT: I changed my example list to be more realistic to my actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Since your "first level" list values are actually lists as well you need to first extract them and then run `order` on the results. For the second version you just need to subsitute 'p.val' as teh extraction index

```
dput(example[ order( sapply(example, "[[", 'p.val')) ] )
  list(list(vals = list(1, 2, 3), param = list(4, 5, 6), p.val = 0.2), 
      list(vals = list(1, 2, 3), param = list(4, 5, 6), p.val = 0.5), 
      list(vals = list(1, 2, 3), param = list(4, 5, 6), p.val = 0.9), 
      list(vals = list(1, 2, 3), param = list(4, 5, 6), p.val = 1.2))
```

That won't change the value of example, so to make it "stick", you would need to assign the result to a name, possibly the same name, `example`.

Comment: Changed my actual list to look more like data. Sorry about that!

Comment: @d.b received the error "unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1' " So I'm assuming my actual variable is not a list type :/

Comment: Not sure what `orderVector1` might be but if the `example` is sufficiently similar in structure then changing  indexing argument to a character, "p.val", should work.